# How can we implement flexview in mariaDB from my local machine?

Tags: database, mariadb, mariasql

I am a newbie to DB world.

I need to implement flexview in mariadb

I tried googling but couldn't find any real-time tutorials

Can someone suggest tutorial with simple implementation of flexiview in MariaDB

Comment: If you are using mariaDB then why did you add the mysql tag to your question, mysql is a completely different database.

Comment: sorry added it by mistake

Comment: @Kmeixner - "Flexviews is a materialized views implementation for MariaDB, MySQL and its forks."  Furthermore, Mariadb and MySQL are forks of the same source, and are almost entirely compatible.

Comment: As a "newbie to the DB world", shouldn't you start with something simpler?  Get your DataWarehouse partially loaded and start writing Reports without flexviews.